# Native and emulated sql statements

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have just started using PDO in my project and I have  few questions.What is the difference between emualated and native sql? What does setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false) do ?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepare.php#107811

Comment: I hope this answer could be used as a nexplanation, as well as a CV-link: [How prepared statements can protect from SQL injection attacks?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8265319/285587)

Comment: I am also curious, what other questions you have? Note the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) - may be you'd find some answers there